Modifying date labels for facet_calendar in ggplot
I have a problem that I can't solve on my own, despite searching for a solution for a long time.
I prepare a chart from data and use facet_calendar.
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1 odczyt.2
'2023-08-14 00:00:00'   362 1.5
'2023-08-14 23:00:00'   633 4.3
'2023-08-15 05:00:00'   224 1.6
'2023-08-15 23:00:00'   445 5.6
'2023-08-16 00:00:00'   182 1.5
'2023-08-16 23:00:00'   493 4.3
'2023-08-17 05:00:00'   434 1.6
'2023-08-17 23:00:00'   485 5.6
'2023-08-18 00:00:00'   686 1.5
'2023-08-18 23:00:00'   487 6.8
'2023-08-19 00:00:00'   566 1.5
'2023-08-19 05:00:00'   278 7.9
'2023-08-19 17:00:00'   561 11.5
'2023-08-19 18:00:00'   365 8.5
'2023-08-19 22:00:00'   170 1.8
'2023-08-19 23:00:00'   456 6.6
'2023-08-20 00:00:00'   498 1.5
'2023-08-20 03:00:00'   961 1.54
'2023-08-20 05:00:00'   397 1.6
'2023-08-20 19:00:00'   532 6.6
'2023-08-20 23:00:00'   493 3.8
'2023-08-21 01:00:00'   441 9.2
'2023-08-21 07:00:00'   793 8.5
'2023-08-21 13:00:00'   395 5.5", header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate (
    DT = as.POSIXct(DT),
    Rok = year (DT),
    Msc = month (DT),
    Godz = hour (DT),
    Dzien = day (DT),
    Date = as.Date (paste0 (Rok, "-", Msc, "-", Dzien))
          )

ggplot (df1 %>% filter (Rok == 2023 & Msc == 8)) +
  geom_col (aes (x = Godz, y = odczyt.1)) +
  facet_calendar(~Date)


The actual data is more complicated and includes data from many years.

I would like to be able to control labels and set the month name to be presented as a full name (currently it is a 3-letter abbreviation)

It should be month(DT, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)

Assuming you are using the facet_calendar function from the sugrrants package, if you check the ?facet_calendar help page, you'll see it offers a format= parameter. To get the full month name use
facet_calendar(~Date, format="%B %d")

